# How to show pop up window only once for the first time when user visits the website in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have written a Lightning Component of Modal Popup to show popup in home page of public community website , it will be shown whenever user visits the website.

My requirement is here is popup window should show only once when the user visits the website for the first time.
But the issue is , whenever the user visits to the website or other sub pages of the site and come back to the home page, again the popup appears. 
In this we want to set the modal popup should be shown only for the first time when the users visit the site , 
as in the popup we are just making sure the user is aware of GDPR rules and regulations .
Once, the user clicks on OK, everytime the GDPR popup should not get open when the user visits the site and home page.

I have refered many Javascript examples but unfortunately I am not able to figure it out , please find my following code and suggest me.

Component :

```
    <!--Use aura:if tag to display/hide popup based on isModalOpen value-->  
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isModalOpen}">            
        <!-- Modal/Popup Box starts here-->
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!-- Modal/Popup Box Header Starts here-->
                <header class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                    <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate"><b>About Your Privacy</b></h2>
                </header>
                <!--Modal/Popup Box Body Starts here-->
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <p>This website uses cookies to improve performance and enhance our visitors’ experience.You may view our privacy policy here.                    
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!--Modal/Popup Box Footer Starts here - class="slds-modal__header", class="slds-modal__footer"-->
                <footer class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium"> 
                      <lightning:button 
                                      label="OK"
                                      title="OK"
                                      onclick="{!c.submitDetails}"/>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </aura:if>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
({
   openModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // Set isModalOpen attribute to true
      component.set("v.isModalOpen", true);


   },

   closeModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // Set isModalOpen attribute to false  
      component.set("v.isModalOpen", false);
   },

   submitDetails: function(component, event, helper) {
      // Set isModalOpen attribute to false
      //Add your code to call apex method or do some processing
      component.set("v.isModalOpen", false);
   },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If each person seeing this webpage is a logged-in community user, then I would try creating a Checkbox field on the User object to track if they've accepted the GDPR message.  Update the `submitDetails` method to mark this new field as true.

When the lightning component loads up, query the current user and the new GDPR checkbox field (either through an Apex SOQL call or trying using the [`force:recordData` Lightning Data Service component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation)).

If the GDPR checkbox is marked true, use `aura:if` and don't show the modal.

Comment: If it's a community site, the checkbox would disable all GDPR popups after the first visit by anyone.

Comment: @sfdcfox I thought it was referring to logged-in community members. Will update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to check if sessionStorage property of javascript is useful? Based on the user details you can try to form a pair of key and value unique to that user visiting and then only have the popup appear. Later on when he visits the page back from any other tab/page of browser it verifies for the same key and value and destroys them only when the user closes the browser/tab. If this is what you want, please try this and let me know.

You can also try localStorage for this.

Thank you.

Comment: sessionStorage expires when the browser is closed. localStorage would be more suitable for this purpose.